# open a zipped file in Dired

Tags: emacs, dired

I'm looking for a way to open a file in a zipped file as Vim can do it with its default configuration.
Dired just shows the list of zipped files but cannot open it while vim can do.
Do you know how to make it work as Vim does? then could I get your tip, please?

Comment: Emacs [does this out of the box too](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/File-Archives.html). Could you be more specific about what's not working? Perhaps a screenshot would help. Also, what OS are you using?

Comment: I have a few custom solutions that I use for OSX, e.g., I can use `unzip` or the `"/System/Library/CoreServices/Archive Utility.app/Contents/MacOS/Archive Utility"`.  I use a later version of `unzip` (6.00) that permits some backup options such as the `-B` flag.  What OS are you using?

Comment: Describe what happens. Does it happen if you start Emacs using `emacs -Q` (no init file)? What is your platform/OS? `Z` should unzip or zip the file or dir at point, and just `RET` should unzip a zipped file on the fly, to open the file unzipped.

Comment: Thanks for all of your comments, Gurus.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that my Evil mode overrides that key-bindings which was 'archive-extract'. Well if you know how to recover this to that macro, please let me know.
I've tried with my shallow elisp knowledge but failed. Please.